# execute Anonymous apex code from VS code, do I need to connect to SF org?

Tags: execute-anonymous, org

SFDC beginner and like to configure my VS code to connect development org.

But before connecting to Org I would like to execute some apex code "hello.apex" created during project creation.

Getting below error
"No default org is set. Run "SFDX: Create a Default Scratch Org" or "SFDX: Authorize an Org" to set one."

The code is below :

```
string tempvar = 'Enter_your_name_here';
System.debug('Hello World!');
System.debug('My name is ' + tempvar);
```

It is obvious this code is not related to any org. So is it mandatory to connect org to execute any code?

Comment: Just my opinion. Instead of spending time on this, use Anynonymus Window in Developer Console in ORG itself.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)!

Answer (score 3):

Apex only runs on an org - it is never run locally. Thus it is essential to set up an org connection in order to execute it.

Comment: To be pedantic, there have been Apex runtime emulators in the past (e.g. BrainEngine IDE's offline Apex mode), but this answer is correct enough for the majority of current subscribers.

Comment: @sfdcfox, I hadn't come across that, so thanks for the reference name. The problem with third-party Apex emulation is that there is no (external) specification of correct function of the Apex language, so you cannot rely on the behaviour always being correct. It would be a quite different thing if Salesforce made the runtime available off-platform, of course. I guess Hyperforce is a step in that direction, but still runs as a (private) cloud service from what I understand and thus would require a connection.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to connect to an org.

Apex is Salesforce's proprietary language, and it is compiled and run on Salesforce's servers. This is true for "Execute Anonymous"/"Anonymous Apex" as well (which makes use of a REST api to send a string of code to Salesforce to be executed).

Anoynmous Apex is never saved/deployed, it's executed once and that's it (though the developer console and VSCode provide mechanisms to retain the code so you don't have to re-write it if you want to execute it again).

Connecting to an org is not the same thing as deploying code to an org. The connection is there for security (you wouldn't want anyone and everyone to be able to run code in your org) and is just part of the workflow. If you have more than one org (say, a production org and a developer sandbox org), you can "connect" to both.

Only one org at a time can be your "default". Having a default org allows you to omit the -u/--username flag (which you can use to specify *which* org to perform an action against).